# AJAX MaskedEditExtender turn input letters into uppercase

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, uppercase, maskededitextender

Can anyone please tell me how to turn all  input to uppercase in a textbox with MaskedEditExtender AJAX control?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX MaskedEditExtender mostly provides masking for things like telephone numbers, dates and postal codes, you don't need to use it to convert input to upper case.

You can easily convert it to upper case using very little javascript:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" runat="server" />
```